# rbind vectors of different length: pad with zero (or NA) instead of recycling

Tags: r, vector, matrix, rbind

Say I have two vectors `v1` and `v2` and that I want to call `rbind(v1, v2)`. However, supposed `length(v1)` > `length(v2)`. From the documentation I have read that the shorter vector will be recycled. Here is an example of this "recycling":

```
v1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 3, 11)
v2 <- c(9, 5, 2)
rbind(v1, v2)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# v1    1    2    3    4    8    5    3   11
# v2    9    5    2    9    5    2    9    5
```

1. Is there any straightforward way I can stop `v2` from being recycled and instead make the remaining entries 0?
2. Is there a better way to build vectors and matrices?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that `rbind.fill` in the `plyr` package does this (with `NA`s not `0`s). I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Hinting on your second question, why the need to stack objects of different lengths into matrices? This is not Excel... Consider keeping such objects into lists: `list(v1, v2)`.

Comment: @flodel, because R has some strange behaviors.  In my case, I've got summaries for three variables.  One of them has no missing values, so the NA slot is empty, and the three results have different lentghs.  Basically, R's summary() function can return a different length object when called on three objects of the same class (very irritating!).

I've spent 30 minutes looking for a simple workaround, and have found none.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use the following:

```
rbind(v1, v2=v2[seq(v1)])

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
v1    1    2    3    4    8    5    3   11
v2    9    5    2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

---

Why it works:
Indexing a vector by a value larger than its length returns a value of NA at that index point.

```
 #eg: 
{1:3}[c(3,5,1)]
#[1]  3 NA  1
```

Thus, if you index the shorter one by the indecies of the longer one, you willl get all of the values of the shorter one plus a series of `NA`'s

---

A generalization:

```
v <- list(v1, v2)
n <- max(lengths(v))
# same:
# n <- max(sapply(v, length))
do.call(rbind, lapply(v, `[`, seq_len(n)))
```

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus, there is only one way to find out...  ;)

Comment: Could you please explain how does lapply(v, `[`, seq_len(n)) works? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Although I think Ricardo has offered a nice solution, something like this would also work applying a function to a list of the vectors you wish to bind. You could specify the character to fill with as well.

```
test <- list(v1,v2)
maxlen <- max(sapply(test,length))
fillchar <- 0
do.call(rbind,lapply(test, function(x) c(x, rep(fillchar, maxlen - length(x) ) )))
```

Or avoiding all the `do.call(rbind` madness:

```
t(sapply(test, function(x) c(x, rep(fillchar, maxlen - length(x)))))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    8    5    3   11
#[2,]    9    5    2    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Although I wouldn't recommend using 0 to indicate no data. 0 and NA are, of course, two very different things.

Comment: @jbaums - true that, I'm assuming whoever uses this code is thinking carefully about their data and why they are filling this matrix.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have many vectors to `rbind` finding longer and shorter vectors could be tedious. In which case this is an option:

```
require(plyr)

rbind.fill.matrix(t(v1), t(v2))
```

or,

```
rbind.fill(as.data.frame(t(v1)), as.data.frame(t(v2)))
```

Comment: This is the most succinct response for my requirements.

Comment: This does work for the summary() function; I get a odd mishmash of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `transpose` from "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(transpose(list(v1, v2)))[]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
# 1:  1  2  3  4  8  5  3 11
# 2:  9  5  2 NA NA NA NA NA
```

`transpose` also has a `fill` argument:

```
setDT(transpose(list(v1, v2), fill = 0))[]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
# 1:  1  2  3  4  8  5  3 11
# 2:  9  5  2  0  0  0  0  0
```

If you have many vectors named in the same pattern--for example, you have v1, v2, v3,..., v10--you can use `mget`:

```
setDT(transpose(mget(paste0("v", 1:10))))[]
```